# modelling data that contains only ones and zeros

Tags: r, logistic, modeling, binary-data

I have a dataset where the predictive variables contain only ones and zeros, and the response variable also contains only ones and zeros. I would like to build a model in `R` to describe their relationship.

I know that a logistic model is suitable for a binary response variable, but what is an appropriate model for binary predictor variables?

Comment: The logistic equation has a range that is continuous, yet it is valid for modeling binomial data.  Why would the transition from a continuous domain to a binomial one not be appropriate?

Comment: You can use the logistic regression also with binary predictor. I do not see where is the problem

Comment: So called 'logic' regression might help in your web search. It neatly describes how binary predictors with complex interactions act on the response.

Comment: Want to point out that the logistic link function is only *one* of several possible for modeling binary outcomes. For example, there are also complimentary log-log, probit and robit models.

Comment: There's a rich theoretical literature on this particular problem, known as "learning boolean functions"; this is probably in more depth than you want and not necessarily immediately applicable, but there's a recent course and book at http://analysisofbooleanfunctions.org.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by building and examining a [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table). There are many [R functions and packages](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/frequencies.html) for doing this - table, prop.table, margin.table, xtabs, and crosstable. Staying with *traditional statistics,* you can then compute many [measures of association](https://web.archive.org/web/20160823051201/http://node101.psych.cornell.edu/Darlington/crosstab/TABLE0.HTM).

You can also approach it from a *machine learning* perspective - in which case, you want to use one of several techniques for [supervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning). If you are new to this, start with decision tree models, such as [C5.0](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/C50/C50.pdf)

Comment: If you can get your hands on a copy of _Categorical Data Analysis_ by Alan Agresti, chapters 1-3 has a very "classical" treatment of contingency tables and measures of association in them.